# Pycairo error while deploying django app on AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My app is deployed on AWS ElasticBeanStalk was working fine up until one hour ago and now it is giving 502 Bad gateway error. When I tried to redeploy the application it gives me the following error

```
2023/05/05 07:41:44.917340 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [self-startup] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/cairo
      copying cairo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/cairo
      copying cairo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/cairo
      copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/cairo
      running build_ext
      Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'cairo' found
      Command '['pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo >= 1.15.10']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycairo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycairo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I don't even have Pycairo in my requirements.txt. Is there any dependency using this in the background, if so How can I find it and resolve this?

I added cairo in .ebextensions as well but it's of no use

requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.2.7
Django==3.0.5
django-cors-headers==3.2.1
djangorestframework==3.11.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.4.0
PyJWT==1.7.1
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
djangorestframework-jwt
django-storages
boto3==1.11.4
zplgrf
reportlab
pandas==1.4.2
python-barcode
pretty_html_table
folium
googlemaps
pyexcel
pyexcel_xls
pyexcel-xlsx
openpyxl
gunicorn
apscheduler
django-smtp-ssl
xlsxwriter
django-simple-search
gmplot
awscrt
awsiotsdk
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have `xhtml2pdf` in your requirements, try installing first `reportlab==3.6.13` and then `xhtml2pdf==0.2.10`

Comment: I have updated the question with my requirements

Comment: Can you try to set the version of reportlab to 3.6.13?

Comment: Had the same issue with a different package however, nevertheless, `reportlab==3.6.13` on top in the requirements fixed it! Thanks!